# Scroll to specific tag name with specific class

Tags: jquery, class, scroll, tagname

Here is what my html code looks like :

```
<div class="code">
    <declaration class="2">
        toto
    </declaration>
    <identifier class="2">
        toto
    </identifier>
    <identifier class="3">
        toto
    </identifier>
    <identifier class="2">
        toto
    </identifier>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript :

```
function gotoDeclaration(){
    $(".code identifier").click(function goto() {
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName($(this).attr('class'));
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].nodeName === 'declaration')
                $('html, body').animate(
                    {scrollTop: list[i].offset().top}, 
                    'fast');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is that if I clic on an element with tag name identifier, it scrolls to the element with tag name declaration, with the same class as the identifier element.

Nothing happens when I clic.

The function is called just after with some others working functions :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
gotoDeclaration();
highlightIdentifiers();
expandCollapse();
});
```

Comment: And what's not working? What happens now when you click?

Comment: When are you calling the `gotoDeclaration` function?

Comment: Nothing happens when I clic.
The function is called just after with some others working functions.

Comment: Too much code for a simple task - posted a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `list[i]` return an HTML element. The problem is that you are using a jQuery function with that: `list[i].offset()`.

To solve that, use [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
$('html, body').animate(
    {scrollTop: list.eq(i).offset().top}, 
    'fast');
```

There is also a better way to code that. Since jQuery is already loaded, use it!

```
function gotoDeclaration(){
    $(".code identifier").click(function goto() {
        var list = $('declaration.'+$(this).attr('class'));
        $('html, body').animate(
             {scrollTop: list.offset().top}, 
             'fast');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to loop through all the elements? 
You don't need all that just for a simple task.

Try this:

```js
function gotoDeclaration(){
    $(".code identifier").click(function goto() {
        var $dec = $('declaration.'+$(this).attr('class'));
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $dec.offset().top}, 'fast');
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  gotoDeclaration();
});
```

```css
identifier,
declaration { height:400px; display:block; }
identifier { background-color:lightblue; cursor:pointer; }
declaration { background-color:lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="code">
    <declaration class="2">
        declaration 2
    </declaration>
    <identifier class="2">
        identifier 2
    </identifier>
    <declaration class="3">
        declaration 3
    </declaration>
    <identifier class="3">
        identifier 3
    </identifier>
</div>
```